# angular $cookies doesnt work in internet explorer 11

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer, cookies

I am using angular-cookie version 1.5.5 and IE 11. I am using angular factory with $cookie to set and get value. setting cookies at one page and retrieve at another page based on it show some div. this solution working fine in chrome and mozilla fine. this is not working in IE. cookies are enabled in IE.

```
app.factory('sharedCookieService', function ($cookies) {

var expireDate = new Date();
return {
    getCookieData: function (key) {
        return $cookies.get(key);
    },
    setCookieData: function (key, value) {
        $cookies.put(key, value, { expires: expireDate });
    },
    ....
   A page var xx = getCookieData(key) getting undefined though successfully setcookie data on B page.
```

Comment: is it possible that the cookie is expiring ? Did you try it without using expires option ?

Comment: @Gonzalo.- i have been setting expire date = next day. my mistake forgot to write code  $cookies.put(key, value, { expires: next day}); so date doesnt expire. i tried without it in IE doesnt work.

Comment: @aka, did you manage to fix this? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: From the comment above I'm guessing that @aka resolved the issue by adding the expiration property to the options object. Unfortunately, I already have that. My cookie worked until recently, and now it doesn't.

Comment: @Tickolas expireDate.setDate(expireDate.getDate() + 1);
                $cookies.put(key, value, { expires: expireDate });